# Angular 2 pass object of options from html to component

Tags: angular2-template

I have a carousel component which can get an object of options to change the way it behaves. I don't want to set them in the component just in case I want to use the same component in another view. I want to know if it's possible to bind or pass this options from the html.

To make it a little bit clear this is the property on the component.ts file:

`defaultOptions: any = {};`

And I want to bind them doing something like this:

`<app-slick [defaultOptions]="{dots: true, arrows: false}">`

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to set it on the carousel component and instead want to set it in the component which uses the carousel? If so you could try implement a @Input() on the app-slick

Comment: The value which you set defaultOptions is specific to that html only, These values wont be available in any other html where you use this component, Is this what you asked?